# building hmatrix on OSX

Tags: macos, random, ghc, hmatrix

I'm trying to build hmatrix-0.16.1.1 on OSX 10.10.1, and I'm running into some undefined C functions and types in src/C/vector-aux.c:

- `struct random_data`
- `random_r()`
- `initstate_r()`

A specific error:

```
src/C/vector-aux.c:738:24:
     error: variable has incomplete type 'struct random_data'
        struct random_data buffer;
```

On a Linux system they seem to be defined in `stdlib.h`, but that doesn't seem to be the case on OSX.

Is there a way to work around this? FWIW, I'm using GHC for OSX (https://ghcformacosx.github.io/) and I've installed `gsl` via `brew install gsl`.

Comment: Also having this problem. I await an answer!

Comment: Looks like it is actively being worked on - watch this thread: https://github.com/albertoruiz/hmatrix/issues/100